# Lotus notes will not launch with xls, xlsx, doc or docx attachments.

Tags: excel, ms-word, lotus-notes, xls

I have a ruby application that allows me to select documents for emailing. The app creates a batch file and downloads it. Clicking on the .bat file launches a notes email window with the attachments populated. When I try this it works fine for PDF, Jpg, and POTX files . However, doc, docx xls and xls give me an error of 'file does not exist'.

the string I am passing via a bat file looks like

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Lotus\Notes\notes.exe"
>   "Mailto:?Attach=\wwwroot\apps\technical_library\public\images\18\Presentation_template.potx?Attach=\wwwroot\apps\technical_library\public\images\31\FAX.doc?Attach=\wwwroot\apps\technical_library\public\images\32\FAX.docx"

If I try to send a bunch of images and pdfs, it creates the email with no problem.

I'm assuming that lotus is blocking the attachments because of 'active content'. How do I get lotus to accept the command line string with doc/xls attachments. ?

Comment: What version of Lotus Notes do u use? and what OS?
I have checked it on Windows+Notes 9 and it worked with your approach.

Comment: I would also double-check the filepath of notes.exe, just for good measure

Comment: @Dmytro Pastovenskyi  - My notes client is 8.5.3. I also tested a zip and that didn't go through.

Comment: @PhilMJones - I checked the filepath and it is correct. I don't think that is the problem since I can send pdf's, jpg's and powerpoint templates.

Comment: @ChrisMendla do you have any antivirus? it looks really odd and I can't reproduce the bug with 9.01

Comment: @DmytroPastovenskyi   I tried running the app in development mode on our server. I had been running it on my laptop locally. When I ran the app from the server, the attachments functioned perfectly. That doesn't make sense to me right now but I'll take it.